# The quantum state measurement in the eigenbasis of unknown hamiltonian

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

Let's say we have some physical system in the unknown hamiltonian $H$, which can be represented with the sum of Pauli matrices. For one two-level system it can be set as $H \propto \vec{n}\vec\sigma$, where we don't know $\vec{n}$.
Now I need to measure the quantum state in the eigenbasis of this hamiltonian. Are there some physical system, which can allow that? Maybe some laser pulse, which collapses a superposition state to the ground or excited state. In fact I don't even need the result of this projective measurement, I just need the state to be collapsed.

Comment: So...you don't know the Hamiltonian, but you want a procedure that projects to its eigenstates? Are you aware that knowing all the  eigenprojections of an operator is equivalent to knowing the operator?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, yes, I see that, projection operators can be expressed via $\vec{n}$ which I don't know. I expect that there is no such a procedure in a general case, but I'm wondering if there exists a specific physical system, where some perturbation over it, which doesn't depend on $\vec{n}$, can perform projective measurement to the current hamiltonian eigenbasis.